# The 2023-01-02 openFDA recall file is missing searchable fields

Tags: openfda

The 2023-01-02 openFDA json file (https://open.fda.gov/apis/device/recall/download/) is missing searchable fields.

For example, the field `cfres_id` is missing (was available in the 2022 json files).

Is this file somehow corrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply here, but it looks like this was a temporary issue - the field is available on the download files now. Let me know if you're still having issues.

Regards,

Violet Wren

openFDA Tech Lead